# How to update OpenGL on Windows Server 2016?

Tags: windows, opengl

I think the title says everything but just to make sure:

I try to update OpenGL on my Windows Server 2016 (V-Server).
Current version is 1.1 and I need > 3.0.

Thanks

Current OpenGL-Viewer output
[image: Current OpenGL-Viewer output]

Full view[image: [Full view]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxehJ.png)

Comment: The OpenGL version depends on your installed graphics driver. What hardware and graphics drivers are you using? Older hardware may not support newer OpenGL versions.

Comment: No graphics card so I try to use software openGL

Comment: Then the question becomes what software you are using and what version that is. Maybe following the 'See details...' seen in image you linked can give some useful information.

Comment: Good point, It shows a very detailed view. But I dont think it helps for an update. Is there An vrsion of opengl that does not requiere a grahic card?

Comment: @Rabbid76: Of course there's a software implementation of modern OpenGL: Mesa has a feature complete software backend and it's even available for Windows.

Comment: @Rabbid76 yes I found that. But why is it so hard to install. I´m death. It´s just so hard to install. But I´ll try.

Answer (score 2):

[Mesa3D](https://www.mesa3d.org/) provides a CPU implementation of OpenGL. The most recent version (17.1.5) supports OpenGL up to version 4.5, but I can't quickly find any information whether that also holds for the CPU implementation. The [FAQ](https://www.mesa3d.org/faq.html) (last update 2012...) does mention supporting OpenGL 3.x presumably also in the CPU implementation, so in any case it should be sufficient for your needs.

Comment: Good Idea, I'll try that soon.